# Laravel: API nested resource for show

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm doing an API with laravel.

So, I created my routes for the nested resource as `Route::apiResource('concerts.positions','PositionsController');`

But is there a way to retreive the position if and only if the concert has a relationship?

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \App\Models\Concert $concert
 * @param  \App\Models\Position $position
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(Request $req, Concert $concert, Position $position) {
    return new PositionResource($position);
}
```

The relationship between Concert and Position is: One Concert hasMany Positions.

Comment: What kind of relationship are you talking about? Between concert and position?

Comment: The concert `hasMany(“App/Models/Position”);`

Comment: So `if ($concert->positions) {...}`?

Comment: That is not going to work. One Concert has Many Position. So if the URL is `api/v1/concerts/{concert}/positions/{position}` I only want to bring the Position if it belongs to the given concert.

Comment: If a position is linked to **one** concert: `if ($position->concert === $concert) { /* bring the position */ }`